# Using Scrapy + Python to login with unknown token

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to make a login request to the following web page using Scrapy `https://www.greatbuyproducts.com/scs/checkout.ssp?is=login&login=T&fragment=login-register#login-register`
**I'm having issues dealing with this web page's parameters because there is no way I can find the token, maybe I have to generate it but I'm not sure**

This is the code I have so far, the issue is where the "token" parts should be.

```
class GreatBuy(scrapy.Spider):
name = "greatbuy"
start_urls = [
    'https://www.greatbuyproducts.com/scs/checkout.ssp?is=login&login=T&fragment=login-register#login-register']

def parse(self, response):
    token =  # I don't know how to get it
    yield scrapy.FormRequest('https://www.greatbuyproducts.com/scs/services/Account.Login.Service.ss?n=2&c=5237170', formdata={'''the token''', 'email': 'my@email.com', 'password': 'mypass', 'send': ''}, callback=self.starscraper)

    def startscraper(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Response('https://www.greatbuyproducts.com/', callback=self.verifylogin)

    def verifylogin(self, response):
        print(response.text)
```

I noticed the query string parameters don't change, can I use them for something here?

** [image: I noticed the query string parameters don't change, can I use them for something here?]
**

Comment: where is the mentioned token using in this request?

Comment: For the initial case, `query string parameters` and `request payloads` are enough, also check for cookies if that won't work.

Comment: There is no token. I think query string parameters are the way to solve the issue but I don't know how to implement that in my code.